# Alternating ESRI scale bars in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar

I'm a recent convert to QGIS from arc and think it's amazing, so much more efficient and usable. It also doesn't crash constantly which helps me keep some of my sanity.

I was having issues finding some features though. 
Mainly an alternating scale bar like in Arc, where there are smaller grading's at the start of the scale bar moving to larger near the end, (to help emphasize distance) and i think it looks cleaner.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that in the spirit of this Q&A site, each thread should only contain one question. Please open another thread for your second question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not totally sure what you are looking for but maybe this comes close:

[image]

Comment: That's a good method to show it, although is there a way to move the smaller sections to the right of 0? All my previous figures have been made in Arc where that's the standard. It's not a massive issue if not though.